# Choosing between device WebView Kit or HTML

Tags: android, html, ios

Im kinda confuse about the thing creating a website for mobile;

Say I have a webpage in mind that I want to create, targeting mobile devices, do I have to use native webview kits that shipped with say for eg. iOS, or I can plainly code HTML+PHP+Javascript+CSS, put it in a server and access it thru Safari browser. (Well, this is just for iOS sample, we also have Android and the plethora of mobile devices)

What are the implications/pros/cons of WebKits vs. HTML, whats the real deal in using Webkits/WebViews? any performance gain, device specific characteristics and so on so forth.

btw, is it really called WebKits (WebViews)?

For a possible duplicate, my apologies.. I just can't relate my problem/issue with one that exist here... please bear with me.

Please enlighten my troubled thinking...

Comment: I don't think it should be discussed here. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: -1 it shouldn't be discussed here

Comment: i understand, i didn't realized that quickly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with an example :

> Designing

In the market by now we have 15 devices with various displays.

(just an assumption we have more than that.)

Now suppose you start making application with different versions for different display sizes.

```
i.e. m.yourapp.com
     yourapp.com
```

etc.

How can you be so sure that these 15 devices are not gonna obsolete one day and you will have to design it again for the new upcoming 15 more devices in the market.

> Development

Going forward, to a web based strong technology that we can rely upon and which is scalable enough has to be used if you have got the answer that with the advancement of time , **the applications would be accessed by web and not through the native android/ios/xyz** based platforms.

So go via web and study **Responsive web design** thoroughly.

Comment: though this is not the appropriate place to ask this question, and yet you still answered, I applaud you and give you my warmest thanks. Cheers!

Comment: make it a rule for life. There are no rules to live , speak and do.